# Magento 3D Secure Problem

Tags: error, paypal

I am running Magento 1.8.0.0 CE and have a problem with Centinel 3D Secure.
All the settings are correct in the backend as it did use to work.

The problem is that as soon as you press the place order button you get the error..

> This card has failed validation and cannot be used.
>   The log output of the 3D Secure Module is - [ErrorNo] => 8030  [ErrorDesc] =>
>   Communication Timeout Encountered

Does anyone know what can be done to fix this? 
From what I can make out its a problem with my hoster.. but no one seems to be able to tell me what I need to get them to change.

Comment: Has no-one experienced this issue before?

Comment: Try this: http://www.zen-cart.com/showthread.php?154305-8030-Communication-Timeout-Encountered-using-3D-Secure

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about a third party extension

Comment: I believe the question is about the Centinel core module.

Comment: Ive spoken to my web host, they cant find any problem on their end.

Comment: Also its not a third party extension, its the Centinel Core Module

Answer (score 1):

The error comes from the `CentinelClient::sendHttp` method. It looks like the `curl` call takes more than the allowed time for a response.
By default the timeout is set to 100 seconds. That should be enough.
Try to see what parameters are sent through the `curl` and replicate that in a custom script for easy debugging.

Comment: The error occurs within about 2 seconds so I don't think its actually timing out.